# Bash print informations on the same point

Tags: bash, shell, printf, echo

In bash how can I print informations on the same point ???

For example how can I do if I want to loop over all files in all subdirectories of an hypothetical root and I want to print on the terminal all the informations always on the same location without printing new lines ??

DIR example

```
--> root
   --> Dir 1
     --> File 1
     --> File 2
   --> Dir 2
     --> File 3
     --> File 4
```

The shell output must be a thing like this :

```
Infos before that I don't want to clear

-------------------------------
Directory    : dirName
File count   : x
File         : fileName
-------------------------------
```

"Count" will remain the same in accord to the current dir but the other informations must be changed in accord to the current subdir (element) of the loop

thanks in advance

Comment: What about just doing a "clear" in every iteration and print the whole thing?

Comment: If that's not an option then you get to play with uses the terminfo codes for your terminal to position your cursor before each print.

Comment: duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/194233/4667

Comment: If it is all on one line, then simply use `\r` instead of `\n` (probably using `printf` unless you want to delve into the arcana of `echo` in `bash`).  If it is on multiple lines as shown, you have to work harder.  You can also investigate the [`tput`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tput) command; low-level but effective.

Comment: I can't just doing a "clear" because i have some useful informations before the block that I want to change dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example:

```
for file in *
do
  printf "\r%${COLUMNS}s\r%s" "" "$file"
  sleep 1
done
echo
```

This prints all files in the current directory on the same line, sleeping for one second after each filename.

In this example, `printf` is used to print an empty argument with a field width that corresponds to the columns of the terminal. This is to clear any previous output still in the line before printing each new `$file`.

Comment: Don't you think using file as a variable is a bad  choice? file itself is a command which returns info about a file.

Comment: @Jahid: In Bash this is not a problem because assignment and use of variables are syntactically unambiguous (`file=value`, `$file`). Furthermore, in contrast to other languages, virtually every name could already exist as a command. How can I know that there is e.g. no `myfile` or `f` command on a certain system (remember that commands can be built-ins, aliases, functions or external programs)?